# What is the limit of a helix as the frequency tends to infinity?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, measure-theory, asymptotics, geometric-measure-theory

Consider the helix parametrized by $r(t) = (\cos(\omega t), \sin(\omega t), t)$, for a given $\omega > 0$, and $t \in \mathbb{R}$. How can we interpret the limit as $\omega \to \infty?$

My initial thought is to define the limit as a varifold, whose weight is on the cylinder of radius $1$, with Dirac measure concentrated on each of the horizontal tangent lines on the circle. My only concern is that it doesn't capture the "holonomic" nature of the helices, as traveling once around a circle always places you back where you started. But perhaps we cannot expect such behavior.

Next, how are we to interpret the limit of a helicoid? A helicoid is parametrized by $r(s,t) = (s \cos(\omega t), s \sin(\omega t), t), -1 \leq s \leq 1$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Again, as $\omega \to \infty$, we can get a varifold limit consisting of the solid cylinder, with Dirac mass concentrated on all the flat tangent planes. However, we get the same issue I mentioned earlier, and furthermore, there are singularities along the $z$-axis, where the curvature is infinite. How do you define the varifold measure along the axis? Would it be by assigning point mass to the vertical tangent lines? Do we assign evenly distributed measure along the planes spanned by $(0,0,1)$ and $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta, 0)$ with $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$?

And finally, what kind of properties would these limits possess? I can see that being an integral varifold is out of the question, but are there other nice properties this limit possesses? I would imagine the limit helicoid would be stationary with respect to the area functional.

Comment: When you talk about varifold convergence, those properties will be forgot, won't they?

Comment: Which properties are you referring to?

Comment: This is probably not relevant, but if you take the limit of the components in the sense of (Schwartzian) distributions, then you get the $z$-axus.

Comment: There is a huge literature around questions that are similar in spirit to yours, and that I think you might be interested in. As I understand it, the situation is the following: you consider a sequence of minimal surfaces $(M_n^2 \mid n \in \mathbf{N})$ that are assumed simply connected, say in the unit ball: $M_n \subset B \subset \mathbf{R}^3$. (For example you could take the helicoids, as you do.) If the areas blow up as $n \to \infty$, then you do *not* get a varifold in the limit, because this would have infinite mass. Instead you get something called a *minimal lamination*, with [...]

Comment: [...] 'nice' convergence away from a singular portion, near which the curvature of the $M_n$ blows up. I believe you can basically picture the $M_n$ like helicoids bent around the singular axis. You might expect the axis to be stationary for length - meaning concentration occurs along a geodesic -, but this is not the case. There are constructions that demonstrate blow-up near any properly embedded $C^{1,1}$ curve (by Meeks and Weber), and other constructions where the singular set is any Cantor set of a line (by Hoffman and White). [...]

Comment: [...] I am not sure whether this is the kind of thing you were looking for... If it is, you can look up, in addition to the names already given, the works of Colding and Minicozzi; Breiner and Kleene I think also did some work in this area. (I can't claim this list is exhaustive, as it's a bit outside my area of expertise.)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to take the [Hausdorff limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance).

In this case helices converges to the infinite unit cylinder and helicoids converge to the whole space.

Another option is to take the [ultralimt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultralimit) of the helicoids with the induced intrinsic metric. (For helices it is not an interesting option; you get the real line.)

Denote by $W$ an infinite cover of the plane branching around.
Take the real line $\mathbb{R}$ and glue continuum copies of $W$ to each point of $\mathbb{R}$ (along the origins).
The obtained metric space is isometric to the ultralimit of these surfaces.